# Resize div to a div inside it

Tags: jquery, scrollto

I have some problems resizing a div with ID `mask` which I use to with a scrollTo() effect.

The `#mask` is sized to 100% browser both sides and `overflow: hidden`, so  when I click on the menu the mask scrolls to the chosen div.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="mask">
  <div id="scrollcontent">
     <div id="content1">
     </div>
     <div id="content2">
     </div>       
     etc.....
</div>
```

The problem is one of the divs inside the mask has content that is too big for the mask div and I can't see it fully. Is there a way to resize the mask div to the content div inside so it could be displayed fully?

Again, the mask is `overflow:hidden` :/

Comment: Perhaps adding [`max-width: 100%`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/max-width) and [`max-height: 100%`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/max-height) to the inner element will solve your problem instead?

Comment: the widths and heights of the divs inside are: 

scrollcontent: width: 400% cos i have 4 divs inside height: 100%
content divs: width: 25% cos i have to use 25% of the scrollcontent width and height: 100% too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to add an extra div at the end that clears all floats

```
<div id="mask">
    <div id="scrollcontent">
       <div id="content1">
       </div>
       <div id="content2">
       </div>
       <div style="clear: both"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can also do some pseudo class styling, using [Micro Clearfix Hack](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/).

**EDIT:** To have it use a scrollbar on the outer div, change `overflow: hidden` to `overflow: scroll`.

Comment: what i intended to do was more like a way to show the scrollbar to scroll down the webpage if the height of the content div was too big for the mask, duno if i have to remove the height 100% or use something to resize it :/